# Android sdk MediaPlayer undocumented error extra code (1, -1015)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using the official MediaPlayer class of the android sdk and I'm facing an error (1, -1015) catched on the "OnErrorListener".
In the MediaPlayer class code the possible extra codes are :

```
public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_IO = -1004;
public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED = -1007;
public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED = -1010;
public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT = -110;
public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_SYSTEM = -2147483648;
```

It's said that the extra code is "Typically implementation dependent" and the error seems to happen only on the samsung devices with android 8.0.

Does anyone have more information on this extra code error "-1015" ?